# ln -s and overwriting a physical directory

Tags: bash, shell, symlink

So I basically have a **directory A** that always exists. I'd like to replace this directory with a symbolik link (this will be done in my deployment script).

I've tried `ln -sf app/cache A` but it does not work, it creates it inside **A** instead of overwriting it.

```bash
$ tree 
.
├── A
│   └── cache -> app/cache
└── app
    └── cache

3 directories, 1 file
```

Is it possible with only `ln` or do I have to remove A beforehand?

Comment: what are the values you provided for MY_TARGET and path_to_A .      
           
For example to create softlink for /webroot/home/httpd/test.com/index.php as /home/vivek/index.php, enter the following command:
ln -s /webroot/home/httpd/test.com/index.php /home/vivek/index.php

ls -l

Comment: Thx for your answer, updated my post @Twinkle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ln` utility may be asked to remove the destination if it already exists by adding the `-f` option.  However, the POSIX standard says that this is done with a call to the C library routine `unlink()`, and about *that* function, the standard says

> The `path` argument shall not name a directory unless the process has appropriate privileges and the implementation supports using `unlink()` on directories.

I have not access to a system where `unlink()` is documented to remove directories, or where the `-f` flag to `ln` is documented to remove directories.

Your solution is therefore to either

```
$ rm -rf /path/to/A
```

or, which would be safer,

```
$ mv -f /path/to/A /path/to/A.orig
```

before creating the symbolic link.

Comment: I'm a little surprised this is the only way